# Read stream from absolute uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to GetResourceStream from absolute uri.

When I am running the below code I am getting null in sri.

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("http://----", UriKind.RelativeorAbsolute));
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.SetSource(sri.Stream);
// Get WriteableBitmap
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(src);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Application.GetResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.95).aspx) is meant to load application resources, not replace HttpWebRequest or HttpClient. According to the docs, this call should throw an ArgumentException instead of returning null

Comment: WinPhone assemblies are incomplete, they don't always follow specs. It should throw, but it does not. Happens very often there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetResourceStream` method is not for http requests. [See the documentation here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms596994%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Returns a resource file from a location in the application package.
>
> uriResource
>   Type: `System.Uri`
>   A relative URI that identifies the resource file to be loaded. If the file has a Build Action of Content, the URI is relative to the application package and you should not use a leading forward slash. If the file has a 
>   `Build Action` of `Resource`, you can use a leading forward slash, but it is not required.

Resource data is a data compiled into your assembly/package

Basically, there are two types of resources which you can load via that method:

- Files Embedded in the application assembly in the application package
  `Uri("/Application;component/EmbeddedInApplicationAssembly.png")`
- Files included in the application package
  `Uri("IncludedInApplicationPackage.png");`

What you're looking for is `HttpClient`

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone/